# Where can I find any good resources(reference books, videos, blogs, etc) to learning LWC and Aura?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

In the future, Lightning Component (Aura, LWC) will be used more in Salesforce development. Therefore, I'm looking for good resources(reference books or other contents (Videos, Blogs, etc)) that may be good references such as design patterns and best practices of Lightning Component (Aura, LWC) and Apex. It can be paid or free, so could you please tell me good resources?

Answer (score 4):

- The best place to learn is [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/superbadges/superbadge_lwc_specialist). A lot of trailmixes available for to accomplish and gain confidence.
- Apart from this, Go through the [Lightning Web Component developer
  guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc). It is very helpful to start with.
- Also, check the [component library](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/components) to  make yourself aware with
  many useful component that you can use in your implementation.
- You can also check the [lwc recipes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes) where you will find the
  conceptual example with working code.
- Some code available project on Lightning Web Component on [trailhead
  apps](https://github.com/trailheadapps)
- Some Videos available on Youtube:-

  - Salesforce official developer channel - [Deep dive into Lightning Web Components](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLgIMQe2PKPSLBLJEWGcr_V-xRvUFA_kUc)
  - video recording on LWC session conducted by me in the past:- [Sunday With Lightning Web Component](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXzifJABQiSwyPDW1UXpE4w/playlists)

Also, check these too:-

- https://salesforcediaries.com/category/lightning-web-component/
- http://www.apexhours.com/lightning-web-components/
- https://salesforcecodex.com/tag/lightning-web-component/

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few resources I can refer to.

The first thing you shall visit is the [official LWC documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc) itself. When I started learning, personally I found it very useful to understand what is LWC and how it works. Basically to get the basic Idea.

Moving ahead, our best friend the Trailhead. There are plenty of badges available all the way from the setting up your development environment to the [Aura Components Specialist](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/superbadges/superbadge_lcf) | [Lightning Web Components Specialist](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/superbadges/superbadge_lwc_specialist)

You can find all [trailheads related to Aura here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/search?keywords=aura).
You can find all [trailheads related to LWC here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/superbadges/superbadge_lwc_specialist).

Also, you can follow this [video series on LWC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBKlTPcb614&t=169s).

**Blogs that I follow the most** 
 https://www.jitendrazaa.com 
https://sfdcmonkey.com/ 
 https://www.sfdcpanther.com/ 
 https://www.sfdcpoint.com/tag/lwc/ 
 http://santanuboral.blogspot.com/